# Invalid column name 'Discriminator' when having a derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a ASP.NET MVC + EF web application, but I get an error when trying to query a list of `Product` using LINQ:

> Invalid column name 'Discriminator'. Invalid column name 'NewProductPhoto'

This happened after I added a derived class from one of my entities.

My entity class:

```
[Table("Product")]
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        ProductPhotos = new HashSet<ProductPhoto>();
        SalesOrderItems = new HashSet<SalesOrderItem>();
    }
    
    // more attributes here
}
```

My new derived class:

```
public class ProductEx : Product
{
    public byte[] NewProductPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

I understand that EF tries to distinguish between `Product` and `ProductEx` but the point is I have no intention to add `ProductEx` to EF model.

1. I don't know why it considers `ProductEx` as part of database model.
2. How can I tell EF to not consider `ProductEx` as database model.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the same way I can exclude a property from entity framework persistent, I can exclude my ProductEx class from entity framework modeling.

The attribute [NotMapped] does the trick.

```
[NotMapped]
public class ProductEx : Product
{
    public byte[] NewProductPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

I still don't understand why EF even considers my derived class for persistence.